# Name a class which contains other dependent classes

Tags: class-design, software-design, class-names

I have a class which will contain list of two dependent classes inside it.

example

```
Class ActivityHolder{
    private ArrayList activityList;
    private ArrayList promiseList;
}
```

My question is how do i name the ActivityHolder class. 
[Edit]

I have a class structure as above.And not the wallet and coin scenario.

Comment: Probably a question better suited to the Programmers Stack Exchange...

Comment: imo , you name a class based on what it represents , not what it contains . On the same , I find prefixing or suffixing the datatype to variable names annoying and redundant , like coinList . If its a collection , just have the name as plural . And also , by convention , variable names are supposed to start with lowercase. And yea , use generics .

Comment: @Richard well the ting is i dont have a corresponding class as wallet .. :(

Comment: @amal thanks for ur insight, however making a variable plural as in coins wont make it explicitly cler that it is a list .. i mean a small s at the end of a long variable name is easy to loose.

Comment: @Archan Do you follow the same with all datatypes ? Like iInteger , dDouble ?.Of course the variable name doesnt make clear it's a list , when i want to know the datatype , that's when I hover the mouse over the variable name in my IDE . So say you named it coinList , and one day your requirement changed and you need a set instead , will you refactor your code . And say , if you still prefer the current naming , maybe you should name it coinsArrayList .

Comment: @amal interesting point amal .. so any suggestions for my actual question , i will think about it .. BTW refactoring is also a 2 click thing in my IDE .. ?.. :)

Comment: @Archan , Wallet's fine if the class is supposed to represent a Wallet. You dont have to name it say WalletContainingCoinsandNotes .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Richard and amal pointed, the class name must be something related to its function.
If it represents a bunch of activities, so it is okay to name it Activities.

```
Class Activities {
    private List activities;  // backlog, planned, other better name (more specific) 
    private List promises;
}
```

Comment: Thanks darlingTon. for your answer.